# Skip field if empty

Tags: javascript, string, skip

I have 4 fields that can be filled in by end user. I would like to send the contents of these in an email but I don't want blank spaces in the email. What I am looking for is a way to ignore those empty field and only return those that have value. I have this piece of code but it only ever returns the last value :

```
var Textbox = Browser.getValue("myTextBox");
var Field1 = Browser.getValue("myField1");
var Field2 = Browser.getValue("myField2");
var Field3 = Browser.getValue("myField3");
var Field4 = Browser.getValue("myField4));  

    if (Field1 != "" ){
    Browser.setValue(TextBox), (Field1 += "\n" +  Textbox));
    }

    if (Field2 != ""){
    Browser.setValue(Textbox), (Field2 += "\n" + Textbox));
    }

    if (Field3 != ""){
    Browser.setValue(Textbox), (Field3 += "\n" + Textbox));
    }

    if (Field4 != ""){
    Browser.setValue(Textbox), (Field4 += "\n" + Textbox));
    }
```

Can anyone help me? I basically need that the Textbox after each statement in updated and used in the next using just Javascript.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What do *Browser.getValue* and *Browser.setValue* do?

Comment: Browser.getValue: gets values of the entry in fields.
Browser.setValue: set values of empty textbox

So here I want to take the value of the field and what is current in textbox and set it as the new value for textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be trying to do something like the following. It goes over all the controls in the form and gets all the values that aren't the initial value and writes them to the textarea on new lines.

```
<script>

// Collect all the non–default values in the form and write
// on new lines to the text area
function consolidateValues(form) {

  // Get the textarea to write values to
  var textArea = form.myTextBox;

  // Get all controls in the form
  var control, controls = form.elements;

  // Variable to hold the consolidated value
  var text = [];

  // Collect all the values, skipping the first control
  for (var i=1, iLen=controls.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    control = controls[i];

    if (control.value != control.defaultValue) {
      text.push(control.value);
    }
  }
  // write the value to the text area
  textArea.value = text.join('\n');

  // Stop form from submitting
  return false;
}

</script>

<form onsubmit="return consolidateValues(this)">
  <textarea name="myTextBox" size="100" rows="10"></textarea>
  <br>
  <input name="myField1">
  <br>
  <input name="myField2">
  <br>
  <input name="myField3">
  <br>
  <input name="myField4">
  <br>
  <input type="submit">  <input type="reset">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you RobG.. I am completely new to Javascript and have very very limited HTML knowledge.. The function consolidateValues(form), what do I pass to it?

Comment: RobG, liked your idea of using an array and I found lovely piece of code on this site to clean up an array so have used that instead. Thank you for your help on this